# How to add only non empty arrays to an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want avoid several `if`s and my question is:

Is there a function or a way to add several arrays ($a, $b) to an array, but only if an array ($a, $b) is not empty?

Given:

```
$a = ['foo' => 'bar'];
$b = [];
```

My code:

```
$c = [];

if (count($a))
{
  $c['a'] = $a;
}

if (count($b))
{
  $c['b'] = $b;
}
```

Yes, I need string keys with a specific name.

Comment: Yes, make a function and don't repeat yourself.

Comment: This looks more like a coding style question to me. If you post a real code fragment you have problems with, you'll get better answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all of your elements are arrays then you can easily cast out the empty ones with [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). For example, taking advantage of the fact that your keys are equal to variable names you can simply do

```
$c = array_filter(compact('a', 'b'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, how about

```
$c = array_filter(compact('a', 'b'));
```

Just kidding. I don't really recommend this. "Smart(ass)" code sucks, especially in php. Be verbose, be readable.

(Looks like the OP didn't get the joke. Too bad...)

Comment: @Jon: it depends, I guess. I asked the OP to give us a real-life example, because foobar codez don't really make sense here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
$c = array();

function addToC(){
   foreach(func_get_args() as $arg){
    if(is_array($arg) && !empty($arg){
     $c[] = $arg; 
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's horribly hacky, and just covering up for bad design, but there are variable variables:

```
$to_do = array('a', 'b');
foreach ($to_do as $key) {
   if (count($$key)) {
     $c[$key] = $$key;
   }
}
```

Note the doubled `$`. e.g.

```
php > echo $bar;
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: bar in php shell code on line 1
php > $foo = 'bar';
php > $$foo = 'baz';
php > echo $bar;
baz
```